# Implement efficient method invocation order possibilities

Tags: c#, enums, method-invocation

I got several methods which does some operations. Let's call these methods for example x,y,z,w.

The user is suppose to let me know somehow the order of invocation of the methods. for example, he can choose to call: `x(); z(); w(); y();` or some other possibility.

The question is, how can I implement something like that efficiently considering that every combination can be possible? I want to know implementation ways, and how to let the user choose the order. (maybe an `Enum` for example? but them will the enum be with values of xyzw, xzyw etc. which will have many possibilities?)

Comment: Do these methods have the same set of parameters (none as it seems) and the same return type (void as it seems), or are there differences?

Comment: Let's say for starters they got the set of parameters and same return type

Comment: If so, you could have a `new Dictionary<string, Action>{{"x", x}, {"y", y}, ... }`. Then somehow get a list of keys from the user, and then: `foreach(string key in list) { Action action; if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out action) { action(); }) }`

Comment: My goal here is that the user will give his request via a GUI interface with predefined actions to choose. That's a bit of a problem regarding how to get the keys..

Comment: So you give the user the `dictionary.Keys` as a list where the user then can select what he/she wants and in what order.

Comment: The ways to present this are sheer endless. Maybe with drag&drop, maybe with two lists (selected/not selected) and buttons, maybe a list with textboxes next to each key, where the user can write a sequence number into...

Comment: @Corak please write an organized answer with an example like you did in the comments and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually did was making a `Dictionary<string, Action>` that maps from the name of the string to its method. Since we're talking about a system with a GUI, I've also added the user some `ComboBoxes` with the available options (the string valus of the keys from the dictionary) and he could choose the order he wantes. Then I just iterate his choices and activate the method accordingly.